# Animating fill color of a vector image button in WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm using the following XAML to create vector image buttons, with animation to change the opacity on mouse hover. Here is the button style:-

```
<Style x:Key="IconButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>                                       
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1.0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.6"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" 
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here is an example of its use:-

```
<Button Width="40" Height="40" Style="{StaticResource IconButtonStyle}">
    <Path Width="30" Height="30" Style="{StaticResource MetroButtonRightStyle}" Fill="Red" />
</Button>
```

The `Path`'s style looks like this:-

```
<Style x:Key="MetroButtonRightStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill" />
    <Setter Property="Data" Value="{StaticResource MetroButtonRightGeometry}" />
</Style>
```

(The resource `MetroButtonRightGeometry` specified in the Data property is a `<Geometry>` which I haven't included here due to the size).

I would like to change the storyboard to alter the image's colour rather than its opacity, but I can't seem to access the `Path`'s `Fill` property from within the storyboard, or whether it is even possible in its present form. Any suggestions?

**Update**

I've found a solution by changing the visual state storyboards to `ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames` like so (note the TargetProperty!):-

```
<ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Content).(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Gold" />
</ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

*and* including a `Fill` on my Path like this:-

```
<Path Width="30" Height="30" Style="{StaticResource MetroButtonRightStyle}" Fill="{StaticResource SomeSolidBrush}" />
```

However it feels a little hacky having to include the Fill, which is basically ignored, and only there to provide a "hook" for the storyboard TargetProperty. Without it I get an error "'Fill' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '{0}.{1}.{2}'".

Comment: Moreover, when you use `Fill="{StaticResource SomeSolidBrush}"`, that resource is shared by all paths that use it. Animating that object would animate the path color of all those buttons.

Comment: @Clemens - interesting, I wasn't aware that such things were possible. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with this solution, which uses triggers instead of storyboards. Having the `Path` within the control template also results in cleaner button markup. I use the Button's `Content` property to specify the icon, i.e. the geometry to apply to the `Path`.

It seems to work, but as a relative WPF novice would welcome comments on my solution.

The style:-

```
<Style x:Key="IconButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Background="Transparent" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Path x:Name="buttonPath" Fill="Blue" Style="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="buttonPath" Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Example usage:-

```
<Button Width="40" Height="40" Style="{StaticResource IconButtonStyle}" Content="{StaticResource MetroButtonRightStyle}" />
```